# Password masking in password field using jquery

Tags: jquery, passwords, masking

How to do password masking as in Android mobile like when we type in a key it shows a key for few seconds and change it to "*". 
I tried the plugin mentioned in [Password masking as in mobiles using js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7304823/password-masking-as-in-mobiles-using-js) it is not optimal. And the jsfiddle http://jsfiddle.net/medopal/X37Wz/ not able to handle backspace and delete. Could you please suggest any other methods to do this? Only using jquery and not to use plugins.

Comment: What's the reason of having it on non-mobile platform?

Comment: It is for one application based on mobile.

Comment: if it will be used on desktop - there is no reason in such behaviour. If it will be used on mobile platform - it will be masked automatically.

Comment: It is not done automatically we need to handle it using jQuery.

Comment: it is done automatically by mobile browsers. Just use input `password`

Comment: I gave input field as <input type="password" name="password" id="password">. It simply showing as entered keys as dots. But i need to show the entered key for few seconds and change it to dot.

Comment: Try https://github.com/timmywil/password123

Answer (score 3, accepted):

here i have done complete solution bin for above query. please check demo link as given below:

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8u

**HTML:**

```
<div id="panel">
  <input type="text" id="txtpwd" name="txtpwd" size="15"/>
  <input type="text" id="txthidden" name="txthidden" size="15"/>
  <div>
    KeyCode Pressed: 
    <span id="keycode">
    </span>
  </div>
</div>
```

**JQuery:**

```
$(function() {
    //Extends JQuery Methods to get current cursor postion in input text.
    //GET CURSOR POSITION
    jQuery.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        if (this.lengh == 0) return -1;
        return $(this).getSelectionStart();
    }

    jQuery.fn.getSelectionStart = function() {
        if (this.lengh == 0) return -1;
        input = this[0];

        var pos = input.value.length;

        if (input.createTextRange) {
            var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
            r.moveEnd('character', input.value.length);
            if (r.text == '') pos = input.value.length;
            pos = input.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
        } else if (typeof(input.selectionStart) != "undefined") pos = input.selectionStart;

        return pos;
    }

    //Bind Key Press event with password field    
    $("#txtpwd").keypress(function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            maskPassword(e)
        }, 500);
    });

});

function generateStars(n) {
    var stars = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        stars += '*';
    }
    return stars;
}

function maskPassword(e) {

    var text = $('#txthidden').val().trim();
    var stars = $('#txthidden').val().trim().length;
    var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    $("#keycode").html(unicode);

    //Get Current Cursor Position on Password Textbox
    var curPos = $("#txtpwd").getCursorPosition();
    var PwdLength = $("#txtpwd").val().trim().length;

    if (unicode != 9 && unicode != 13 && unicode != 37 && unicode != 40 && unicode != 37 && unicode != 39) {
        //If NOT <Back Space> OR <DEL> Then...
        if (unicode != 8 && unicode != 46) {
            text = text + String.fromCharCode(unicode);
            stars += 1;
        }
        //If Press <Back Space> Or <DEL> Then...
        else if ((unicode == 8 || unicode == 46) && stars != PwdLength) {
            stars -= 1;
            text = text.replace(text.charAt(curPos), "");
        }
        //Set New String on both input fields
        $('#txthidden').val(text);
        $('#txtpwd').val(generateStars(stars));
    }

}
```

**Demo:** http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8u

Comment: Thanks. But how it handle if we delete a character from txtpwd? As of now it is not getting deleted in hidden field.

Comment: Hi, have you visited above demo link..? It is working fine as your query.

Comment: If you type "123" in txtpwd input element and 
Now, As per your query I have set keypress event on txtpwd so if your cursor on txtpwd after first star like " * | * * " and you press Delete then it removes "2" from hidden element value "13".

Comment: Same as for backspace Now it you press backspace "*|*" then it removes "1" from hidden element value.

Comment: Here, i have set on checks that if cursor in txtpwd before first char like "|***" and press backspace same as if cursor after last char like "***|" and press Delete key then it doesn't do anything.

Comment: Thanks. I changed the keypress event to keydown for my requirement.

Answer (score 3):

based on keyur at codebins.com code above, this great little answer here https://stackoverflow.com/a/4843500/1056285 and also https://stackoverflow.com/a/1431109/1056285 (for making the backspace actually delete without bugs) i adapted the solution to take into account backspace too!

```
$(function() {
    //Extends JQuery Methods to get current cursor postion in input text.
    //GET CURSOR POSITION
    jQuery.fn.getCursorPosition = function() {
        if (this.lengh == 0) return -1;
        return $(this).getSelectionStart();
    }

    jQuery.fn.getSelectionStart = function() {
        if (this.lengh == 0) return -1;
        input = this[0];

        var pos = input.value.length;

        if (input.createTextRange) {
            var r = document.selection.createRange().duplicate();
            r.moveEnd('character', input.value.length);
            if (r.text == '') pos = input.value.length;
            pos = input.value.lastIndexOf(r.text);
        } else if (typeof(input.selectionStart) != "undefined") pos = input.selectionStart;

        return pos;
    }

    //Bind Key Press event with password field    
    $("#txtpwd").keypress(function(e) {
        setTimeout(function() {
            maskPassword(e)
        }, 500);
    });

    $("#txtpwd").keydown(function(e) {
        if (e.keyCode == 8) {
            setTimeout(function() {
                maskPassword(e)
            }, 1);
        }
    });

});

function generateStars(n) {
    var stars = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        stars += '*';
    }
    return stars;
}

function maskPassword(e) {

    var text = $('#txthidden').val();
    var stars = $('#txthidden').val().length;
    var unicode = e.keyCode ? e.keyCode : e.charCode;
    $("#keycode").html(unicode);

    //Get Current Cursor Position on Password Textbox
    var curPos = $("#txtpwd").getCursorPosition();
    var PwdLength = $("#txtpwd").val().length;

    if (unicode != 9 && unicode != 13 && unicode != 37 && unicode != 40 && unicode != 37 && unicode != 39) {
        //If NOT <Back Space> OR <DEL> Then...
        if (unicode != 8 && unicode != 46) {
            text = text + String.fromCharCode(unicode);
            stars += 1;
        }
        //If Press <Back Space> Or <DEL> Then...
        else if ((unicode == 8 || unicode == 46) && stars != PwdLength) {
            stars -= 1;
            text = text.substr(0, curPos) + text.substr(curPos + 1);
        }
        //Set New String on both input fields
        $('#txthidden').val(text);
        $('#txtpwd').val(generateStars(stars));
    }

}
```

You can have a look below:
http://codebins.com/bin/4ldqp8u/38

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer [here](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/8259) and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bummi i didn't include the code because i had some issues with code formatting and i was to lazy to see what's wrong. But i figured it and now i add the code too. Thanks for the suggestion :)

Comment: This *almost* worked, but doesn't work correctly when you select the whole field and press delete. I found this script, which worked better: http://www.sitepoint.com/better-passwords-1-the-masked-password-field/.

Answer (score 1):

IE 10 has that feature. May be some one can rip it off? :|

[image: IE 10 on Windows 8]

Also, I wrote a simple snippet basing on this [here](http://jsbin.com/igufof/3/) that should get you started on coding your own.

EDIT: check out the code here:

```
<form action="#" onclick="return false;">
<input type="text" id="pv" name="passval" value="password" /><br>
<input type="password" id="p" name="pass" value="passwordsd" /><br>
<button id="b">Show</button>
</form>
<script>
$("#b").mousedown(function(){
  $("#pv").val($("#p").val());
}).mouseup(function(){
  $("#pv").val("");
});
</script>
```