# jquery equivalent to Android password box

Tags: jquery, android

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Password masking in password field using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11822963/password-masking-in-password-field-using-jquery)

Hey all i have been trying to find some code that mimics the Android password box (the way it shows you one letter before you proceed to the next letter which in turn blocks the previous letter from being seen).

Does anyone know of code in Jquery for this? Or even know what this would be called?

Thanks!

[image: android password]

Comment: I have the code that shows this but can not update this post without another 4 votes to reopen it! VOTE so i can paste the code! :o)

Comment: Post your code at the duplicate question, please.

Answer (score 0):

I think that behavior depends on the operating system of the mobile, or at least on the mobile's browser.
Found a similar question with a jQuery code, I hope is what you're looking for: [Password masking in password field using jquery](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11824481/1095101)