# Masking input field text to show bullets using angular JS

Tags: angularjs

I have an input field with type =tel(required for devices).
Need to mask the text field so that it shows bullets instead of text(like a password).
Any idea how to do that using angular JS.
Achieved the same for all  browsers using  -webkit-text-security : disc;
However it  doesn't work for IE.
Hence wondering if we can achieve it through Angular JS.

Till now have tried creating a custom directive that changes the input type but it doesn't seem to work.

```
    myDirectives.directive('changeType', function() {
       return {
            priority: 500,
            compile: function(elem, attrs) {
              attrs.$set('type', 'password', false);
            }
       }
    });
```

Comment: can you post your html as well? or create a jsfiddle?

Comment: HTML is pretty basic
A simple input tag 
<input type='tel' ng-model='passcode'>
Using tel to display numpad on devices.
In other words I need a password field with numpad for mobile devices.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Change text to dots in text field with CSS/Javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3574474/change-text-to-dots-in-text-field-with-css-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need angular to set the type, here is a plain old javascript implementation:

http://plnkr.co/edit/mCa1gvg52q0pFM6FRj7T?p=preview

```
window.onload = function(){
    init(); 
}
function init(){
    var x = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];
    var style = window.getComputedStyle(x);
    console.log(style);
    if(style.webkitTextSecurity){
        //do nothing
    }else{
        x.setAttribute("type","password");
    }
}
```

But in reality, there is a restriction, and you are not supposed to change input types dynamically. So angular may support this in code, but browser restrictions would/should prevent it from being changed; you might even run into being able to change it as above, but since it's evaluated once it might not work the way you expect.

See here: [AngularJS: can't change input type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15148456/angularjs-cant-change-input-type)

You'd be better off with setting the input type on page load, or using an ng-switch to flip between input types.